# Is it possible to smite with ranged weapons using either Branding Smite or Banishing smite?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin, ranged-attack

Most of the paladin's smite spells start out with

> The next time you hit a creature with a **melee weapon** attack...

or

> The first time you hit with a **melee weapon** attack...

Neither [*Branding smite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/branding-smite) nor [*Banishing smite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishing-smite) has this weapon restriction, instead it says:

> The next time you hit a creature with a **weapon** attack before this spell ends...

**Taking this into account, is it possible to apply these two smites on ranged weapons?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Banishing Smite and Branding Smite can be used with ranged attacks, because ....

### Spells are not limited based on similarly named spell mechanics

---

Despite sharing a similar name, Banishing Smite and Branding Smite are not actually related to the other smite spells or Smite ability of the Paladin class. So, this means that one only need to adhere to limitations present in the individual spell.

P.S. -  The other smite spells (blinding, searing, staggering, thunderous, and wrathful) do actually require melee weapon attacks.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes, your reading is correct.

There's no wording that restricts both spells from being used only with melee weapon attacks, unlike the other smite spells. I also checked the [Errata of the Player's Handbook](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PH-Errata.pdf), there doesn't seem to be any corrections either. So... smite away!